# Unequal Strings : HP 5”6'5A and HP 5"6'5A

Tags: java, mysql, compare, dataformat

I have two tables A and B.
Table A have a column called `a_value varchar(20)` and B have `b_value as varchar(20)`.
Both table data filled by different source by `using java`.

`A` from `Excel sheet`.
`B` from `xml`.

```
HP 5"6'5A  - xml(table A)

HP 5”6'5A - Excel (Table B)
```

I want to take `a_value` which is `not` available in `b_value`.

But i always get above mentioned value.

How can i solve this issue?

cheers..

Comment: smells like different codepages (or maybe whitespace at the end). can you dump the real table structure and data and post it here ... maybe you will see for yourself when dumping the data ;o)

Comment: Change a font. The Excel one has a smart quote.

Comment: Ok. will thy this. I have created the sqlfiddle demo [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9195/1]

Comment: @KennyTM I have changed the font Arial from Bitstream Charter. But same problem.:(

Comment: Thanks for your effort folks... solution updated in the question.

Comment: Please post the answer as an answer and accept it.  It's completely permitted by the site guidelines, and will make this a more complete question if anyone else encounters this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed by adding below condition

```
 String value = "HP 5”6'5A"; 
 value = value.contains("”")?value.replace("”", "\""):value);
```